# Preferred Stock pricing model

Tags: equities, risk, pricing, modeling

I am trying to build a model to price a preferred stock. I want to model the dividends as random payments. I can't find any papers online on the subject. Does anyone have a reference for me?

Comment: Naively searching "stochastic dividends" returns lots of papers. Why are those not relevant?

Comment: Naively searching "preferred stock" returns  David Emanuel: A Theoretical Model for Valuing Preferred Stock, The Journal of Finance Vol. 38, No. 4 (Sep., 1983), pp. 1133-1155 Paper does not seem available online, go to a library.

Comment: @alex c I have that paper in my library and I’ve read it. It’s rather old and uses a structural model. I’m looking for more recent literature.